# The xpage ssjs code to open xe:dialog does not open dialog but change document mode from edit to read

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib, xpages-ssjs

My Xpage has five sections for workflow. Section 1 submit button works fine.
For second section submit button I'm calling xe:dialog  box (using ssjs) to get some user inupt and it does open the xe:dialog box. But original document is now in read mode and submit button is not visible

If I remove the section 1, the section 2 button open dialog and does not change the document mode of original document.

Here is a sample code of xpage with dialog box and button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"
    dojoTheme="true"
    dojoParseOnLoad="true">
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:dojoModule
            name="dijit.Dialog"></xp:dojoModule>
        <xp:dojoModule
            name="dijit.form.Button"></xp:dojoModule>
        <xp:dojoModule
            name="dijit.form.TextBox"></xp:dojoModule>
    </xp:this.resources>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument
            var="document1"
            formName="MetalWorking">
        </xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:panel>
        <xp:panel>

            &#160;
            <xp:button
                value="Lab Man Approval"
                id="button4">
                <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:document1.isEditable() & (document1.getItemValueDate("Section1DateCompleted")!=null) & (document1.getItemValueDate("Section2DateCompleted") == null)
}]]></xp:this.rendered>
                <xp:eventHandler
                    event="onclick"
                    submit="true"
                    refreshMode="complete"
                    immediate="false"
                    save="true">
                    <xp:this.action>
                        <xp:executeScript>
                            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:var d=getComponent('dialog2');
d.show();}]]></xp:this.script>
                        </xp:executeScript>
                    </xp:this.action>
                </xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:button>
            &#160; &#160;<xp:br></xp:br>
            <xe:dialog
                id="dialog2">
                <xp:panel
                    style="background-color:rgb(226,226,226)">
                    <xp:table>
                        <xp:tr>
                            <xp:td>
                                <xp:label
                                    value="Response"
                                    id="responseArea_Label1"
                                    for="responseArea1">
                                </xp:label>
                            </xp:td>
                            <xp:td>
                                <xp:inputText
                                    id="responseArea1">
                                </xp:inputText>
                            </xp:td>
                        </xp:tr>
                    </xp:table>
                </xp:panel>
            </xe:dialog>
        </xp:panel>
    </xp:panel>
    <xp:table>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:label
                    value="Doc history:"
                    id="docHistory_Label1"
                    for="docHistory1">
                </xp:label>
            </xp:td>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:inputText
                    value="#{document1.DocHistory}"
                    id="docHistory1">
                </xp:inputText>
            </xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
    </xp:table>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: You can not expect people to look through your 700+ lines of code. Please cut your code example down to what's necessary to understand your problem

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has far too much code for people to dig through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure thats because of the "document1.isEditable()" and not because of all the other parts in your if your statement?

if i change your rendering code just like that

`<xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript: document1.isEditable() }]]></xp:this.rendered>`

the button is pretty much visible.

Comment: The button is shown when document is in edit mode. It calls the xe:dialog and when xe:dialog closed the document1.isEditable()=false. Added the onComplete event dialog box button to click edit button on parent button and it is working. But then I realized that it is not helpful in executing rest of code in the calling button on parent xpage. Ideally dialog save button should close the dialog and transfer back control to calling button. Is it possible?